# Filter API result with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

---

I consume API with react with this snippet of code:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    items: null
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  return client
    .get('/api/v1/product/list')
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({items: response});
      return response
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw err
    });
}
```

and then I got a result like this from the API:

[image]

My questions are, how do I to filter the API result and then consume the **results** inside **data**..?

Comment: I got 2 vote down in my questions, btw whats wrong with my questions..?
I will edit and improve that if something wrong with my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this,

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    items: null
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  return client
    .get('/api/v1/product/list')
    .then(response => {
      //extract data from response 
       let {data} = response;
      this.setState({items:data.results});
      return response
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw err
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man, you really know I want exactly :)